# How to use the inserting commands/functions in the mini-buffer?

Tags: minibuffer, insert

Assume that I have defined a function like below with some keybinding (e.g.`M-p`).

```
(defun foo () (interactive)
(insert "something very long") )


(global-set-key [(meta p)] 'foo)
```

If I hit `M-p` while the cursor is at the main buffer, of course the text `something very long` is inserted. But when the cursor is at mini-buffer by hitting `M-p` the text `foo` is inserted.

Is there a way to redefine this function in such a way to work in both main buffer and mini-buffer?

Comment: You might need to bind the key in one of the various `minibuffer-XXXX-map`s.

Comment: Unless the string will always vary, it is usually better to send the string directly to the function behind the scenes instead of going through the mini-buffer, which is probably being opened by functions such as `read-string` and the like.  If there is a specific function that you wish to have receive the string, consider editing the question with an example so that a forum participant can demonstrate how to pass the string directly to the function programmatically and bypass the mini-buffer entirely.

Comment: @lawlist during evaluation by `M-:` I need to insert pairs of parentheses and putting the cursor between them. This was my main motivation to use a function which does this automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work is: (a) the minibuffer has its own local keymap, (b) `M-p` is bound in that local map to a different command, and (c) a local keymap takes precedence over the global keymap.

To have your command work for `M-p` in the minibuffer, you need to bind it to `M-p` in one or more of the minibuffer keymaps.  It is probably sufficient to bind it in keymap `minibuffer-local-map`, where it will be inherited by the other minibuffer keymaps:

```
(define-key minibuffer-local-map (kbd "M-p") 'foo)
```

See the Elisp manual, node [Text from Minibuffer](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Text-from-Minibuffer.html).